# r create a new Indicator column based on combination of variables

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-transform

I have a dataset with two colums, ID, Group.

```
ID       Group
10       Red
11       Red
13       Blue
13       Red
15       Blue
15       Blue
17       Blue
17       Red
17       Red
19       Blue
19       Undecided
23       Blue
23       Undecided
23       Undecided
```

My goal is to create a third indicator column that takes a value based on the combination of values in ID and Group. Expecting a third column , `Indicator` like this.

```
ID       Group          Indicator
10       Blue           Single
11       Blue           Single

13       Blue           Blue-Red
13       Red            Blue-Red

15       Blue           Blue-Blue
15       Blue           Blue-Blue

17       Blue           Blue-Red
17       Red            Blue-Red
17       Red            Blue-Red  

19       Blue           Blue-Undecided  
19       Undecided      Blue-Undecided 

23       Blue           Blue-Undecided 
23       Undecided      Blue-Undecided   
23       Undecided      Blue-Undecided
```

I tried `case_when` but it became too complicated and gave up. Any help in much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. by the "Blue-Blue" when in all other cases you seem to take the unique values when you have duplicates. What exactly is the logic here? What if there are three values in a group? What determines order, ie "Blue-Red" vs "Red-Blue"

Comment: @MrFlick, good question. Blue is the baseline. I am interested in all combinations that involve Blue. So Red-Blue or Blue-Red does not matter, its just one Blue-Red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `case_when` version using `dplyr` that doesn't have too many cases

```
library(dplyr)
dd  %>% 
  mutate(Indicator = case_when(
      n()==1 ~ "Single",
      n_distinct(Group)==1 ~ paste(rep(first(Group),2), collapse="-"),
      TRUE ~ paste(sort(unique(Group)), collapse="-")
    ), .by=ID)
```

which produces

```
   ID     Group      Indicator
1  10       Red         Single
2  11       Red         Single
3  13      Blue       Blue-Red
4  13       Red       Blue-Red
5  15      Blue      Blue-Blue
6  15      Blue      Blue-Blue
7  17      Blue       Blue-Red
8  17       Red       Blue-Red
9  17       Red       Blue-Red
10 19      Blue Blue-Undecided
11 19 Undecided Blue-Undecided
12 23      Blue Blue-Undecided
13 23 Undecided Blue-Undecided
14 23 Undecided Blue-Undecided
```

tested with

```
dd <- data.frame(
  ID = c(10L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 23L, 23L, 23L), 
  Group = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Undecided", "Blue", "Undecided", "Undecided")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave`

```
transform(
  df,
  Indicator = ave(
    Group,
    ID,
    FUN = \(x) ifelse(length(x) == 1,
      "Single", 
      paste0(rep(unique(x),length.out = 2), collapse = "-")
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   ID     Group      Indicator
1  10       Red         Single
2  11       Red         Single
3  13      Blue       Blue-Red
4  13       Red       Blue-Red
5  15      Blue      Blue-Blue
6  15      Blue      Blue-Blue
7  17      Blue       Blue-Red
8  17       Red       Blue-Red
9  17       Red       Blue-Red
10 19      Blue Blue-Undecided
11 19 Undecided Blue-Undecided
12 23      Blue Blue-Undecided
13 23 Undecided Blue-Undecided
14 23 Undecided Blue-Undecided
```

Comment: @MrFlick aha, thanks for capturing the error. Now I think it is fixed.